# Store lines of a text using fgets?

Tags: c, fgets

Here's this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    int i=0;
    char number[1024];
    char *n[1000];
    FILE *fp;
    
    fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    
    if (fp==NULL){
        printf("ERROR\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    while (fgets(number,1024,fp)!=NULL){
        n[i]=number;
        i++;
    }
    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("%s",n[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);  
    return 0;
}
```

What i have to do is read a file that contains some numbers and store the lines of the file so i can access them. The output i wanted (which is the content of the txt file i want to copy) would be:

853
482
512
205

But instead i'm having:

205
205
205
205

Any suggestions on how to store all numbers of the file instead of only the last number?

Comment: Think about what this ' n[i]=number;' does.  It's not what you thought when you wrote it:)

Comment: Maybe you wanted `int n[1000];`, `n[i] = atoi(number);`, `printf("%d\n", n[i]);`?

Comment: All  `*n` are pointing to the same place: `number`, and after each loop you are overwriting the content of `number` with the content read in `fgets`. So it is always print only the last number. If you want to store more number you need to dedicate a memory to each one.

Answer (score 3):

You end up printing the same value because `n` is pointing to the same memory, that is the last string you read with `fgets()`. You can use `malloc()` and `realloc()` to have the result you seek.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i = 0;
  char(*n)[1000]; /* pointer to an array of 1000 chars */
  FILE *fp;

  if (argc < 2)
  {
      fprintf(stderr,"Not enough arguments\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  n = malloc(sizeof(*n));

  if (n == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  while (fgets(n[i++], 1024, fp) != NULL) /* strcpy is redundant here,since we can just save in the buffer directly*/
  { 
    n = realloc(n, (i + 1) * sizeof(*n)); /* realloc each time so you can store another string */

    if (n == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr,"ERROR\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++)
  {
    printf("%s", n[j]);
  }

  free(n);

  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Although, the above will work, it will be more efficient to initially `malloc` an X amount of memory and if you end up needing more, call `realloc()`.

Comment: It worked just fine, thank you for your answer was very helpful. I'm struggling to undertand why it keeps rewriting even when using *(n+i) instead of n[i].

Comment: @Stubr It’s the same syntax. The array syntax is equivalent to what you wrote. It’s just syntactic sugar:)